Proving the implicit equation of the parabolic boundary of a plane domain defined by two parameters
$p,q \in [0,1]$ I have the equation:
$(x,y) = pq(2,1) + p(1-q)(-1,-1) + (1-p)q(-1,-1) + (1-p)(1-q)(1,2)$
I want to show that the parabolic boundary connecting $(2,1)$ and $(1,2)$ is given by
$5(x-y+1)^2 = 4(3x-2y+1)$.
I have tried substituting using the first two equations but I do not get the correct representation.

As $p$ and $q$ vary over $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, the first equation gives you a triangular region of 2D space. But your implicit equation is a curve, not a region. I don’t see how they can be equivalent.

In the answer from @JeanMarie, we set $p=q$, which I gives us a median curve of the triangular region.

The triangular region is a Bézier patch of degree $1 \times 1$. If the point $(1,1)$ was not repeated, it would be a quadrilateral region. Repeating the point $(1,1)$ collapses one side of the quadrilateral, giving us a triangle.

You are correct. I have updated the question accordingly. I was interested in finding the parabolic boundary which connects two points

I have taken the liberty to change your title into a more meaningful one, which is important for future searches? Do you agree ?

Let us start from the expanded form :
$$\begin{cases}x&=&5pq-2(p+q)+1\\y&=&5pq-3(p+q)+2\end{cases}\tag{0}$$
When we let $p,q$ vary, say in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ we see that we have points covering the whole area situated in "triangle" $ABC$ with $A(2,1), B(-1,-1), C(1,2)$ where sides $AB$ and $BC$ are line segments and side $AC$ is a parabola (see Fig. 2). But no point inside the parabola is reached. One can prove that each point inside this "triangle" is reached twice.
Why in particular do we have the parabola as a boundary ?
Let us express the sum and the product of $p$ and $q$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ :
$$\begin{cases}S&:=&p+q=x-y+1\\P&:=&pq=\tfrac15(3x-2y)\end{cases}\tag{2}$$
Now let us ask the following question : being given $x$ and $y$ in the plane, does there exist 2 real values $p,q$ such that (2) holds ?
We are now with a classical reasoning : $p$ and $q$ are roots of the following quadratic equation
$$z^2-Sz+P=0$$
in variable $z$ which has real roots $p$ and $q$ if and only if its discriminant is positive :
$$S^2-4P \ge 0 \iff \ (x-y+1)^2-\tfrac45(3x-2y)\ge 0$$
This inequality describe the exterior of the parabola. The interior of the parabola is never reached. And, in the limit case, we find the looked for equation
$$(x-y+1)^2-\tfrac45(3x-2y)=0\tag{3}$$
Last, but not least, this limit case corresponds to the double root case, precisely $p=q$, giving the Bezier curve with representation :
$$M=(1-p)^2 A + 2p(1-p)B + p^2C$$

Fig. 1 : The yellow curve corresponds to (3) ; the little circles are points obtained using (1) for values of $p$ from $0$ to $1$ with a small step (see Matlab program below).
 for p=0:0.02:1
    q=p
    V=p*q*[2,1]+(p*(1-q)+(1-p)*q)*[-1,-1]+(1-p)*(1-q)*[1,2];
    plot(V(1),V(2),'or');hold on;
 end;
 fimplicit(@(x,y)(5*(x-y+1)^2-4*(3*x-2*y+1)))

Remarks :
See also "blossoming" (I have given references in a comment) and Coons patches

Fig. 2 : Values of $p, q$ are taken here in $[0,1]$.

How are we able to let p=q if they can both vary independently

Yes your working is correct, small type in Y equation - should be +2 not +1. Thanks. Since I am looking for the boundary, which this calculation gives, I assume that using p not equal to q gives points within the boundary ?

In fact, the correspondence between the parabola (which is a Bezier curve) $M= t^2 A + 2t(1-t) B + (1-t)^2 C$ and your representation $pq A + (p(1-q) + (1-p)q)B + (1-p)(1-q)C$ has a name : it is called "blossoming" : see paragraph 4 in this document. I had seen it before but wasn't able to remind it at first. See also here.

This answer is great. Thank you very much for your help.
